# Pywavelets applied to time series

Tags: wavelet, time-series, pywavelets

I'm new on this field. I am applying a discrete wavelet decomposition to a timeseries and the decomposition yields subsets of the data, specifically the half. Nothing wrong with that since that is the way a wavelet decomposition works.

[image]

But I see the `approximation 2` looks the same as the complete timeserie, just half the length. So what's happening with the rest of the data?

I would like to understand what's happening here with the result and how to get the processed signal with the same length (~5000).

Answer (score 1):

For DWT, the original signal is downsampled by a factor of two at each level of decomposition. It's based on filter banks, in which data is downsampled by a factor of 2, i.e., by a low pass filter - one obtains the approximation coefficients (low frequency) and if it's by a high pass filter, then you get detail coefficients (high frequency).

In your case, the original signal had `~5000` data points, if you decompose that with level 2, you're going to get half the signals at each level thus leaving you with the `detail_2` and `approximation_2` having `~1250` data points.

In the case you want to get the original data length, you can reconstruct back by adding the detail and approximation coefficients together. There's a package in python for this, `PyWavelets`.